# Code not running in the desired order in ngOnInit(){}

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I am starting out with ionic 4 and typescript. In my ngOnInit I am calling a function and logging to the console some variable which the function should have updated. Problem is, they seem to be running in the wrong order, so the variables are not being updated.

I also log to the console in the function so I know the function locateUser() is working as desired. just not in the correct order.

```
let lat: number ;
let  lon: number ;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-start',
  templateUrl: 'start.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['start.page.scss'],

})

export class StartPage implements OnInit{ 
  constructor(
    private alertCtrl: AlertController
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.locateUser();
    console.log('Current', 'lat ' +  lat + ' lon ' + lon);

  }

  private locateUser() {
      if (!Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('Geolocation')) {
        this.showErrorAlert();
        return;
      }
      Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then()
      .then(geoPosition =>{
        const coordinates: Coordinates = {
          latitude: geoPosition.coords.latitude,
          longitude: geoPosition.coords.longitude,
          altitude: geoPosition.coords.altitude,
          accuracy: geoPosition.coords.accuracy,
          altitudeAccuracy: geoPosition.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
          heading: geoPosition.coords.heading,
          speed: geoPosition.coords.speed,

      };
        lat = coordinates.latitude;
        lon = coordinates.longitude;
        console.log('Current', 'lat ' +  lat + ' lon ' + lon);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.showErrorAlert();
      });
  }
```

Comment: As your function has asynchronous call, it's obvious that your console in `ngOnInit()` is getting printed before your function completes execution.

Comment: And how would I change this from an asynchronous call? Thanks

Comment: Let it remain as it is! Just add a new method call in `then` part of the your async call. And in that method, print your `lat` and `long`.